# Optimize MySQL query with range and multiple joins

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, sql-optimization, amazon-aurora

I'm looking to optimize the MySQL query below. Is there a multi column index that would be more successful? I have tried (`created_date`, `rep_id`) with no luck. Any suggestions to speed this query up are appreciated.

```
SELECT
customer.rep_id AS `ID`,
COUNT(*) AS Count,
rep.first_name,
rep.last_name

FROM customer 
INNER JOIN appointment ON customer.id = appointment.customer_id
INNER JOIN rep ON customer.rep_id = rep.user_id
INNER JOIN user ON rep.user_id = user.id

WHERE customer.rep_id != 0
AND customer.saved = 0
AND customer.deleted = 0
AND customer.created_date >= '2017-01-01'
AND customer.created_date < '2017-02-01'
AND appointment.current = 1
AND appointment.realStatus IS NOT NULL
AND (   appointment.realStatus not in('rescheduled','cancelled')
    OR (appointment.closed_by_id IS NULL
     OR customer.rep_id != appointment.closed_by_id)
    )
AND user.knocks = 1
AND user.deleted = 0
GROUP BY customer.rep_id
ORDER BY `Count` DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Here is the `EXPLAIN` output:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: customer
type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY,rep_id,created_date  
key: NULL
key_len: NULL
ref: NULL
rows: 354846
Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: rep
type: ref
possible_keys: user_id
key: user_id
key_len: 4
ref: customer.rep_id
rows: 1
Extra: Using index condition

id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: user
type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
key: PRIMARY
key_len: 4
ref: rep.user_id
rows: 1
Extra: Using where

id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: appointment
type: ref
possible_keys: realStatus, customer_id, created_date
key: customer_id
key_len: 4
ref: customer.id
rows: 1
Extra: Using where
```

Comment: Have you tried using between for the date range? Not sure if that would make it start using the index or not, but worth a try.

Comment: If you're using a date range for a calendar month, an index on the month-year only of the customer.created_date would allow a calculated equal instead of a range for the monthly query.

Comment: Is rep a view of contact?

Comment: Can you show us DDL? It's likely that the query optimizer is making incorrect guesses about which indexes work. You may need to create a compound index with all the columns in your where clause....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly rewritten of query for readability and visual association to other tables in the join..

```
SELECT
        customer.rep_id AS `ID`,
        COUNT(*) AS Count,
        rep.first_name,
        rep.last_name
    FROM 
        customer 
            INNER JOIN appointment 
                ON customer.id = appointment.customer_id
                AND appointment.current = 1
                AND appointment.realStatus IS NOT NULL
            INNER JOIN rep 
                ON customer.rep_id = rep.user_id
                INNER JOIN user 
                    ON rep.user_id = user.id
                    AND user.knocks = 1
                    AND user.deleted = 0
    WHERE 
            customer.rep_id != 0
        AND customer.saved = 0
        AND customer.deleted = 0
        AND customer.created_date >= '2017-01-01'
        AND customer.created_date < '2017-02-01'
        AND ( appointment.realStatus not in('rescheduled','cancelled') 
            OR (    appointment.closed_by_id IS NULL 
                OR  customer.rep_id != appointment.closed_by_id ))
    GROUP BY 
        customer.rep_id
    ORDER BY 
        `Count` DESC
    LIMIT 
        50
```

You probably need multiple composite indexes to help the query.  Additionally, I shifted some of the query elements to better match where the criteria is applicable (such as appointment and user).  This helps to identify a better index option too.  That said, I would offer the following indexes on each

```
table        index
customer     (saved, deleted, created_date, rep_id )
rep          (user_id)
appointment  (customer_id, current, realStatus)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great. I have an index (rep_id, saved, deleted, created_date) that is not quite as efficient in the EXPLAIN output, but executes in about the same time and works with a lot more of my queries. Can you explain the index order to me? New to this optimization stuff :)

Comment: @b.dig, take a look at these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658786/optimizing-a-very-huge-mysql-table-query-or-mysql/27659098#27659098   and let me know if that helps you understand context.  Indexes should match primary WHERE or JOIN criteria in context to optimized records (per example the other link describes).

Comment: [_More on indexing_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql), including why to have `saved` and `deleted` first (due to `=`) and `rep_id` last (for "covering").

Answer (score 0):

Add an index hint: `from customer use index (created_date) inner join ...`

(Note that `use index` doesn't do what it says; it just makes the optimizer ignore any indexes you don't mention.)

Other than that, making the appointment customer_id index be on `(customer_id,current)` might help.

Comment: Forced the created_date index and it doesn't speed it up as much as I was hoping. I'm new to optimization... is there a multi column index that would work better?

Comment: Does explain now show it using an index for customer?

Comment: Yes, however, it does not run any quicker. Here is the updated EXPLAIN for the customer table: 1, SIMPLE, customer, range, created_date, created_date, 6, 115032, Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: did you get a chance to try with a (customer_id,current) index on appointment?

Comment: Yes- doesn't really speed the query up and I have to force the optimizer to use it. But thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a compound index - something like:

create index multi on customer (id, rep_id, created_date);

MySQL uses just one index for each table (depending on version, engine, etc.), and if it thinks the existing indices aren't going to be helpful, it may ignore them.

I'm assuming customer.saved and customer.deleted are both columns with few possible values - yes/no, 0/1 etc. They tend to be ignored by query optimization engines.

Comment: It is almost always useless to start a composite index with the `PRIMARY KEY`.  An index on _only_ a "flag" usually won't be used, but a _composite_ index that includes a flag follows different rules.